# Could validation data be a generator in tensorflow.keras 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

In official documents of [tensorflow.keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model),

> validation_data could be: tuple (x_val, y_val) of Numpy arrays or tensors
>   tuple (x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights) of Numpy arrays
>   dataset For the first two cases, batch_size must be provided. For the last case, validation_steps could be provided.

It does not mention if generator could act as validation_data. So I want to know if validation_data could be a datagenerator? like the [following codes](https://github.com/filipetrocadoferreira/end2endlobesegmentation/blob/master/train.py):

```
net.fit_generator(train_it.generator(), epoch_iterations * batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, verbose=1,
                  validation_data=val_it.generator(), nb_val_samples=3,
                  callbacks=[checker, tb, stopper, saver])
```

Update:
In the official documents of [keras](https://keras.io/models/sequential/), the same contents, but another sentense is added:

> - dataset or a dataset iterator

Considering that

> dataset For the first two cases, batch_size must be provided. For the last case, validation_steps could be provided.

I think there should be 3 cases. Keras' documents are correct. So I will post an issue in tensorflow.keras to update the documents.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it can, that's strange that it is not in the doc but is it working exactly like the `x` argument, you can also use a `keras.Sequence` or a `generator`. In my project I often use `keras.Sequence` that acts like a generator

Minimum working example that shows that it works :

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten

def generator(batch_size): # Create empty arrays to contain batch of features and labels
    batch_features = np.zeros((batch_size, 1000))
    batch_labels = np.zeros((batch_size,1))
    while True:
        for i in range(batch_size):
            yield batch_features, batch_labels

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(125, input_shape=(1000,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_generator = generator(64)
validation_generator = generator(64)

model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=100, epochs=100, steps_per_epoch=100)
```

> 100/100 [==============================] - 1s 13ms/step - loss: 0.6689 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.6448 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
>   Epoch 2/100
>   100/100 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.6223 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.6000 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
>   Epoch 3/100
>   100/100 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.5792 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.5586 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
>   Epoch 4/100
>   100/100 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 0.5393 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.5203 - val_accuracy: 1.0000

Comment: Can validation_data be a [GeneratorEnqueuer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/GeneratorEnqueuer)?  From the source code of [tensorflow.keras](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py) I found that validation_data could be  
`iterator_ops.Iterator`,  `iterator_ops.OwnedIterator`,
                                   `dataset_ops.DatasetV2`,
                                   `data_utils.Sequence`

Comment: Not exactly, you need to start the `GeneratorEnqueuer` on a generator (`ge = GeneratorEnqueuer(generator(64))`) then `start` it on your workers or whatever, `ge.start()` and  finally `get` the resulting generator `output_generator = ge.get()` that will be placed on the `fit` model.fit(output_generator ,epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=5)

Comment: I have known that train_dataset could be GeneratorEnqueuer just as what you said. What I asked here is if validation_dataset could be GeneratorEnqueuer?? I tried it, and I found that for train_data, it works. But for validation_data, it does not work.

Comment: According to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit , using generator as `validation_data` arguement is not supported in `keras.fit` anymore

Comment: @MasoudMasoumiMoghadam I have a feeling that the point of this post is that it does work, though it is not in the docs, doesn't it?

Comment: @MasoudMasoumiMoghadam But you are right, the source code show that it is not: just a couple of elements seem to be taken: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L1447